# What is the meaning of $A^2$ if $A$ is a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Like I already wrote in the title, I would like to know what the meaning of $A^2$ is if $A$ is a set. I think that it might have the same meaning as the power set of $A$.

Comment: Do you mean $A\times A?$

Comment: Sometimes it is used to signify the set of maps $f:2\rightarrow A$, but I don't see this too often, where $2=\{0,1\}$.

Comment: I don't understand how this is predicate-logic or logic related.  Can you clarify the problem?  As it is, I think it would be more suited for set-theory (already chosen) and _number theory_.

Comment: Your right Ian I changed the flags

Comment: The power set is $2^A$. The answer below starts to explain why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constructing natural number $0,1,2,\cdots$ we have $2:=\{0,1\}$ as a set. In general $A^B$ denotes the collection of functions with domain $B$ and codomain $A$. So $A^2$ can be interpreted this way as the collection of functions $\{0,1\}\rightarrow A$. Then formally an element of $A^{2}$ has the form $$\left\{ \langle0,a\rangle,\langle1,a'\rangle\right\}$$
with $a,a'\in A$.

So it is obvious that there is a one-to-one relation with ordered pairs $\langle a,a'\rangle\in A\times A$.

So $A^2$ and $A\times A$ are in this sense isomorphic as sets.

Comment: So would that mean that if I have an set A := {1,2,3,4} and A^2 would mean A×A so I would get for A^2 =={(1,1);(1,2);(1,3);(1,4);...}?

Comment: Is my edit enough to give you understanding?

Comment: Yes thanks alot for your effort!

Comment: Glad to help. You are very welcome.